# How to handle visibility and isEnabled for multiple buttons and other elements effectively

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have some elements on my main filter, in my wpf application.
But I don´t want to set visibility and isEnabled one by one in get/set. Is there more elegant way, how to change it from view model?
Thank you! :)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Show please what you have now and explain why is it a problem. If *multiple* is a problem, then you probably just need to organize collection to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DataTrigger` to change some properties of your `Button` based on the view model properties:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="viewModelInstance"></local:MyViewModel>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button DataContext="{StaticResource viewModelInstance}" Content="My Button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <!-- Default style is Visible and Enabled -->
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAllowed}" Value="False">
                        <!-- Hide and disable when IsAllowed is false -->
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Assuming you have a view model class defined like:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; } = true;
    //Put more logic here of course.
}
```

`MyViewModel` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to automatically notify the UI to update the view when the `IsAllowed` property changes, for example like this:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    //Backing field for IsAllowed
    private bool _isAllowed = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the IsAllowed property.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAllowed {
        get => _isAllowed; set {
            if (_isAllowed != value) {
                _isAllowed = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsAllowed)));
            }
        }
    }
    //INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

You can also look into the `IValueCOnverter` interface and XAML converters for other ways.